# python class attribute cannot used as an argument for constructor?

Tags: python, class, constructor, arguments, class-attributes

In python 3 I found that class attribute can be used as a argument in `__init__()` function, like below:

file test.py:

```
class Foo:
    var1 = 23333
    def __init__(self, var=var1):
        self.var = var
```

run in cmd:

```
C:\Users\rikka\Desktop>py -3 -i test.py
>>> f1=Foo()
>>> f1.var
23333
```

but by using a dot.expression, when init this class, interpreter will report an error:

file test2.py:

```
class Foo:
    var1 = 23333
    def __init__(self, var=Foo.var1):
       self.var = var
```

run in cmd:

```
C:\Users\rikka\Desktop>py -3 -i test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Foo:
  File "test2.py", line 3, in Foo
    def __init__(self, var=Foo.var1):
NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined
```

I just don't know why interpreter cannot find name 'Foo' since Foo is a name in the global frame in the environment. is there something scope related concept about python class that I don't fully understand?

Comment: Please post what you actually get without hand editing. Your second code sample with the `>>>` prompt looks like part of an interactive Python session, but the traceback comes from executing a script. If you had tried this code interactively you would have seen that it is the class definition which throws the exception not the call to construct the object.

Comment: @Duncan thanks for advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function defaults are set at *function definition time*, not when being called. As such, it is not the expression `var1` that is stored but the *value* that variable represents, `23333`. `var1` happens to be a local variable when the function is defined, because *all* names in a class body are treated as locals in a function when the class is built, but the name `Foo` does not yet exist because the class hasn't finished building yet.

Use a sentinel instead, and *in the body of the function* then determine the current value of `Foo.var1`:

```
def __init__(self, var=None):
    if var is None:
        var = Foo.var1
    self.var = var
```

I used `None` as the sentinel here because it is readily available and not often needed as an actual value. If you do need to be able to set `var` as a distinct (i.e. non-default) value, use a different singleton sentinel:

```
_sentinel = object()

class Foo:
    var = 23333

    def __init__(self, var=_sentinel):
        if var is _sentinel:
            var = Foo.var1
        self.var = var
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to reference Foo during its very construction. At the moment that `Foo.__init__` is defined, which is when `Foo.var` is evaluated, `Foo` does not exist yet (as it's methods, i.e. `Foo.__init__` itself, have not been fully constructed yet).

Function/method default parameters are resolved during function/method definition. Classes are only available after definition. If a class method definition (i.e. parameters) references the class itself, you get a circular dependency. The method cannot be defined without the class, and the class cannot be defined without its method.

See Martijn Pieters reply on how to actually approach such dependencies.

Comment: This is Python 3; *all* classes automatically inherit from `object`.

Comment: Missed that one in the opening post, thanks for pointing it out. I've removed the bit to avoid confusion.